# How do I Import jsoncpp to my project sub directory

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, jsoncpp

I am working on a project with this directory structure.

```
WeaselTestApp
    --build
       ...
    --weasel
        ...
        --CMakeLists.txt
   --main.cpp
   --CMakeLists.txt
   --conanfile.txt
```

root CMakeLists.txt file content

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(WeaselTestApp LANGUAGES CXX)
add_executable(WeaselTestApp main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(weasel)
target_link_libraries(WeaselTestApp PRIVATE Weasel)
```

weasel CMakeLists.txt file content

```
add_library(Weasel Utils.cpp HttpMethod.cpp HttpStatus.cpp Request.cpp Response.cpp Router.cpp Server.cpp)

include_directories(${CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS_JSONCPP})
set(jsoncpp_DIR "/home/emmanuel/weasle/build")
find_package(jsoncpp REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(Weasel PRIVATE jsoncpp)
```

root conanfile.txt file content

```
[requires]
jsoncpp/1.9.5
gtest/1.11.0

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
cmake_find_package
```

when I run the command `cmake --build /home/user/weasle/build`, I get this error

```
[ 10%] Building CXX object weasel/CMakeFiles/Weasel.dir/Utils.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object weasel/CMakeFiles/Weasel.dir/HttpMethod.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object weasel/CMakeFiles/Weasel.dir/HttpStatus.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object weasel/CMakeFiles/Weasel.dir/Request.cpp.o
In file included from /home/user/weasle/weasel/Request.cpp:1:
/home/user/weasle/weasel/Request.h:5:10: fatal error: json/json.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <json/json.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
gmake[2]: *** [weasel/CMakeFiles/Weasel.dir/build.make:118: weasel/CMakeFiles/Weasel.dir/Request.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:126: weasel/CMakeFiles/Weasel.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:101: all] Error 2
```

How can I properly use the `jsoncpp` package in the project, I plan on making the content of weasel folder a package in future, so I don't want to include jsoncpp package in the root cmake folder.

Comment: It is necessary to ``target_link_libraries()`` the right targets. And the usage of ``CONAN_INCLUDE_DIRS_JSONCPP`` is unnecessary and not recommended.

Comment: You need to drop ``cmake_find_package`` from the conanfile.txt, it is colliding/overwriting with ``CMakeDeps``. You should be using only ``CMakeDeps`` and ``CMakeToolchain``

Comment: When you call ``cmake ...`` you need to either pass the ``-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=.../conan_toolchain.cmake`` or call ``cmake --presets ...``. Please check the docs tutorial in https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages.html

Comment: You also need to drop ``set(jsoncpp_DIR "/home/emmanuel/weasle/build")``, this shouldn't be done, the ``conan_toolchain.cmake`` will be providing the paths to the generated files.

Comment: @drodri I update the ./weasel/CMakeLists.txt file to this below
`add_library(Weasel Utils.cpp HttpMethod.cpp HttpStatus.cpp` `Request.cppResponse.cpp Router.cpp Server.cpp)`
`find_package(jsoncpp REQUIRED)`

`target_link_libraries(Weasel PRIVATE ${CONAN_LIBS})`
`target_link_libraries(Weasel PRIVATE jsoncpp)`
`
Same error.

Comment: It should be `target_link_libraries(Weasel PRIVATE JsonCpp::JsonCpp)`. If you link to `jsoncpp`, you tell CMake to link the library only, not the imported target, so you miss the all abstraction which makes CMake properly add include dirs and interface definition to compile flags, and library to link flags.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes actually `jsoncpp` doesn’t link that way.

Comment: This isn't neccessary. 

`set(jsoncpp_DIR "/home/emmanuel/weasle/build")`

Comment: Sure it links that way: https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/69098a18b9af0c47549d9a271c054d13ca92b006/jsoncpp-namespaced-targets.cmake#L1-L7

Comment: You are still not using the right targets or commands. It is better if you post an issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, this format here is not good for this kind of support.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes I can’t remember where I came across my solution but I did try those to no avail. You would expect that to work but ugh . [There are comments on that too on GitHub](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/455#issuecomment-477307969)

Comment: Several imported targets are defined (`jsoncpp_lib` for shared lib, `jsoncpp_static` for static lib, `JsonCpp::JsonCpp` as an alias target for either shared or static depending on what has been built). CMakeLists of jsoncpp is a mess because library author doesn't care and let contributors do whatever they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I properly use the `jsoncpp` package in the project

**Do this**

```cpp
find_package(jsoncpp REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Weasel PRIVATE jsoncpp_lib)
```